# Probability Problems Check

Tags: probability

there are two probability problems that my friend asked me to solve:

1, Suppose it rains in Spain an average of once every 9 days, and when it does, hurricanes have a 4% chance of happening in Hartford. When it does not rain in Spain, hurricanes have a 1% chance of happening in Hartford. What is the probability that it rains in Spain when hurricanes happen in Hartford!

2, A roulette wheel has the numbers 1 through 36, 0, and 00. A bet on six numbers pays 5 to 1( that is, if one of the six numbers came up, you get back your \$1 plus \$5). How much do you expect to win with one bet on six numbers?

For first question, I used conditional probability and get P(A|B)=(1/9)*(1/25)/(1/9)=0.04

For the second question, I used elementary mathematical expectation formula: E(X)=6*6/38-32/38=2/19

But the answers seemed wrong. Can someone help me figure out where I did wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: According to Higgins's Theorem, "in Hartford, Hereford and Hampshire, hurricanes hardly ever happen."

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to use Bayes's rule.
\begin{align*}
P(\text{rain} \mid \text{hurricane}) = \frac{P(\text{hurricane} \mid \text{rain}) P(\text{rain})}{P(\text{hurricane} \mid \text{rain}) P(\text{rain})+P(\text{hurricane} \mid \text{no rain}) P(\text{no rain})}
\end{align*}

2) Looks good. Edit: Your answer is correct if your definition of "5 to 1" is as you described, but from Graham Kemp's answer, it seems you may have gotten the definition wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> > Suppose it rains in Spain an average of once every 9 days, and when it does, hurricanes have a 4% chance of happening in Hartford. When it does not rain in Spain, hurricanes have a 1% chance of happening in Hartford. What is the probability that it rains in Spain when hurricanes happen in Hartford!
>
> For first question, I used conditional probability and get P(A|B)=(1/9)*(1/25)/(1/9)=0.04

If $A$ is the event "it rains in Spain", and $B$ is "hurricane in Hartford", then you want:

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb P (A\mid B) & = \dfrac{\Bbb P(A \cap B)}{\Bbb P(B)}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{ \Bbb P(A)\;\Bbb P(B\mid A) }{ \Bbb P(A)\;\Bbb P(B\mid A)+\Bbb P(A^c)\;\Bbb P(B\mid A^c) }
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\dfrac 1 9\cdot\dfrac 4{100}}{\dfrac 1 9\cdot \dfrac{4}{100}+\dfrac 8 9\cdot \dfrac 1{100}}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{4}{4+8} 
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{1}{3}
\end{align}$$

> > A bet on six numbers pays 5 to 1( that is, if one of the six numbers came up, you get back your \$1 plus \$5).  How much do you expect to win with one bet on six numbers?
>
> For the second question, I used elementary mathematical expectation formula: E(X)=6*6/38-32/38=2/19

Correct procedure, wrong figures.

The amount you win is the amount by which your fortune *changes*.  That is: how much *more (or less)* you have than *before* you put up the stake.

If a bet pays 5 to 1 then you receive $\$5$ on a win but have the $\$1$ stake taken away on a loss.

$$\Bbb E(W) = 5\times \frac{6}{38} - \frac{32}{38} = {-\frac{1}{19}}$$

---

Simpler example: if a fair coin toss pays 2 to 1, then the amount you would expect to win on a $\$1$ stake is: $\$0$.   Yes/No?